# Reassigning Dependent Instance Variables

Tags: python-3.x, variable-assignment, instance-variables

I have made a Point class in python that functions like a LinkedList, i.e. every instance of Point Class points to the next object in the chain. These Points also store a distance value, the distance between self.next and self. I permute the order of this chain by updating the .next instance variable of every member of my list of Points. However, this doesn't update the distance calculation. Do I really need to reassign the .distance instance variable every time, or is there a better or more elegant way?

A good,simple example of what I mean is below. The first print statement is 0,5,  the second is 5,5. I want to update the b value without actually reassigning them both every time.

```py
class Tester():
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a = a
        self.b = a+5

Hank = Tester(0)
print(Hank.a,Hank.b)
Hank.a=5
print(Hank.a,Hank.b)
```

I would like to be able to change the value of a AND b, so that the second print statement is 5,10. I know that I can reassign b, but it seems like there should be a better way.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Tendril. Its not clear to me what you are asking for help with - perhaps restructure your question to include what you think should be happening. If your question is not in relation to the Travelling Salesman problem, maybe remove that part.

Answer (score 0):

For pointers and linked lists, it appears your answer is here: https://www.codefellows.org/blog/implementing-a-singly-linked-list-in-python/

In general:

Once you pass in a value to be assigned for *a*, both *a* and *b* are initialized. Since your class doesn't iterate over values, *b*'s value won't update simply because the value of *a* was reassigned. You have to re-call the class to do that.

If you are manually assigning like you are in your post, you could do this:

```
class Tester():
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a = a
        self.b = a+5

Hank = Tester(0)
print(Hank.a,Hank.b)
Hank = Tester(5)
print(Hank.a,Hank.b)
```

Return:

```
0 5
5 10
```

Or more elegantly (of course needing to update based on the range/value/whatever you're seeking):

```
class Tester():
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a = a
        self.b = a+5

i = 0
while i <= 100:
    Hank = Tester(i)
    print(Hank.a, Hank.b)
    i+=5
```

Return:

```
0 5
5 10
10 15
15 20
20 25
25 30
30 35
35 40
40 45
45 50
50 55
55 60
60 65
65 70
70 75
75 80
80 85
85 90
90 95
95 100
100 105
```

Lastly, you're not printing the commas like your post suggests. You need to add those in a string. One example is to update the print statement by using the f-string:

```
print(f"{Hank.a}, {Hank.b}")
```

Result:

```
0, 5
5, 10
10, 15
15, 20
20, 25
25, 30
30, 35
35, 40
40, 45
45, 50
50, 55
55, 60
60, 65
65, 70
70, 75
75, 80
80, 85
85, 90
90, 95
95, 100
100, 105
```